# What about `enable_if` makes it hard for compilers to generate readable error messages?

Tags: c++

One of the "critics" of `enable_if` is that it produces a complete mess of error messages. So e.g. Bjarne Stroustrup wants to introduce Concepts to get around this (see [his talk (youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2egL4y_VpYg) or [the example (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_(C%2B%2B)#Compiler_diagnostics)).

My Question: What makes it technically so challenging for compilers to produce readable output with `enable_if`?

Comment: [Relevant](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/70086/why-are-c-template-error-messages-so-horrific)

Comment: Concepts could produce a mess of error messages too, see [example](http://honermann.net/blog/2016/07/18/refining-concepts-improving-error-messages/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::enable_if` sounds like something special that can enable/disable *function templates* and *class templates* given a compile-time boolean expression... but it isn't. Here's a possible implementation:

```
template <bool TCond, typename T = void> 
struct enable_if {};

template <typename T> 
struct enable_if<true, T> { using type = T; };
```

The above means:

- If `TCond` is `true`, `enable_if` will define an inner `type` type alias.
- If `TCond` is `false`, `enable_if` will **not** define an inner `type` type alias.

When `enable_if` is being used to enable/disable something, we refer to its `::type` internal alias:

```
template <typename T, 
          typename = std::enable_if</* something */>::type>
void foo(T) { /* something */ }
```

If `::type` exists for the above `/* something */` condition, `foo` is well-formed. Otherwise, **substitution failure** occurs, triggering [**SFINAE**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae).

The compiler **isn't aware of our intent** and deals with eventual errors by tracing the source of the error. It isn't aware that we meant to enable/disable some function/class in a set of functions/classes - it cannot therefore give us meaningful and intuitive errors. The best it can do is pinpoint the source of the error and give us a backtrace.

If `enable_if` was a special keyword or a compiler intrinsic, then the errors would very likely be easier to parse.